# What is a starred message in chat?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

For the `Talkative` badge, I need to post 10 messages with 1 or more starred in chat.
I don't understand what a starred message is and can't find information about it anywhere.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When someone thinks your message is important or when they simply like it (for one reason or another) they click the star on it. When you hover a chat message, you'll see this:

> [image: star]

Click on that star to star someone else's message. When one or more people click on that star, the message will appear on the right of the chat window, under the users' list. A starred message will appear like this, with the number indicating how many people starred it:

> [image]

In order for you to get the badge, you must post at least 10 messages in chat, with one or more of them getting stars from other users.

**Note**: if you see this star ([image]) next to some message in the list on the right, that message is not simply starred, it's **pinned**. A message can be pinned by moderators, by the Team or by room owners. A pinned message will stay on the top of the list to signal a particularly important message (that's why only mods and the Team can do this) that function like announcements to those who attend the chat room.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Chat FAQ](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#star):

> You can star both rooms and messages by clicking the star next to the respective item.

And:

> Feel free to star any message you feel is particularly useful or worthy of summarizing in the transcript.

So, if enough of your messages on chat have been starred by people, you will get the talkative badge.